# Execute the event listener code immediately if the event dispatched at least once

Tags: javascript, events

```
// Event listener registered before event dispatched.
document.addEventListener('myappready', function (e) {
 console.log("I am always on time :) ");
});

// Dispatch the event.
document.dispatchEvent(new Event('myappready'));

// Event listener registered after event dispatched.
document.addEventListener('myappready',  function() {
   console.log("I am always late :( ");
});
```

It gives the output:

```
I am always on time :)
```

But I want the output:

```
I am always on time :)
I am always late :(
```

Comment: Down vote is ok. But at least give me some feedback!

Comment: When you wait for the bus, but you're two minutes too late, will you catch the bus?

Comment: You can't do that like this. You can do it with rxjs https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs

Comment: sorry I misunderstood what you were asking. Most code is executed in the order you write it. If you don't add the event listener until after the event has happened,  then the computer has no way of knowing what's going to happen in the future. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by implementing a wrapper for your addEventListener, this could then keep track of if the event has already been fired, if so just call the callback immediately.

eg.

```js
function myAppReady(cb) {
  if (!myAppReady.ready) {
    document.addEventListener('myappready',function () {
      myAppReady.ready = true;
      cb();
    });
  } else cb();
}
myAppReady.ready = false;


// On time..
myAppReady(function () {
  console.log("I am always on time :) ");
});

// Dispatch the event.
document.dispatchEvent(new Event('myappready'));

// Event listener registered after event dispatched.
myAppReady(function() {
   console.log("I am always late :( ");
});
```

Comment: Kids see the question's literal meaning. Legends see what OP wants!